# Is there an upper limit for passing nvarchar(max) to a database?

Tags: sql-server, csv, nvarchar

I'm importing CSV data into a SQL Server via an `nvarchar(max)` parameter in a stored procedure and then splitting it using a function. I can't use Bulk insert for various reasons.

It's likely that these strings could get very large indeed.

Is there an upper limit to what I can pass through an SP call before things get hairy? I can split the string into batches easily but I'd like to know how small to make my batches.

Comment: String manipulation is not SQL servers strong point.  You might be better to split it in code and then insert it using appropriate parameters for the field types.

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx -- Variable-length Unicode string data. n defines the string length and can be a value from 1 through 4,000. max indicates that the maximum storage size is 2^31-1 bytes (2 GB). The storage size, in bytes, is two times the actual length of data entered + 2 bytes. The ISO synonyms for nvarchar are national char varying and national character varying.  simply put 2 gig of data on an NVARCHAR(max)

Comment: And of course [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx)

Comment: I think the comments from @MC-ND are more what the questioner was wanting.  You can certainly send some hundreds of kilobytes per call. What are you using to pass the data in.

Comment: @xQbert, if you add that as an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx --

Variable-length Unicode string data. n defines the string length and can be a value from 1 through 4,000.

max indicates that the maximum storage size is 2^31-1 bytes (2 GB).

The storage size, in bytes, is two times the actual length of data entered + 2 bytes. The ISO synonyms for nvarchar are national char varying and national character varying. simply put 2 gig of data on an NVARCHAR(max)